# Limiting to at max N concurrent calls to a static method in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm

Consider the following static method:

```
public void static foo() {
  // some heavy operation operating on a shared resource.
}
```

Assume that the system becomes unstable when the number of concurrent calls to `foo()` exceeds ten (10).

If I in this scenario spin up 100 threads all hammering `foo()` with requests then the application will become unstable since we exceed the number of concurrent requests which the system can handle.

One way to increase stability to the price of limited concurrency is the change the code to:

```
public void static synchronized foo() {
  // some heavy operation operating on a shared resource.
}
```

The system will now be able to handle 100 threads all hammering `foo()` with requests since only one call at a time will be allowed to `foo()`.

What about the scenario that I want to limit access to `foo()` so that only `N` concurrent requests are allowed? What is the simplest way to achieve such a limitation in Java?

Comment: Might want to look into this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184147/countdownlatch-vs-semaphore

Comment: for those who have similar problem, but with async call see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69234939/1220560

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) initialized with 10 permits. Acquire a permit at the beginning of the method, and release it (in a finally block) at the end of the method.

Answer (score -1):

[CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

May solve your problem.

It comes in blocking and non blocking.

Edit: Fix URL

Comment: no, the latch is used for entirely different tasks (like waiting N tasks to complete). the answer is misleading and mostly incorrect. You are looking for Semaphore.