# Maximum number of Spring "@Async" calls at a time

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have an async method which i need to call multiple times. Is there any limit that i can have only these many calls at a time? if yes, what is the best way to restrict. Is thread.sleep is fine or is there any other way?

I might need to call the method more than 50k times. In different system its behaving differently with out any restriction. For one system it has completed successfully, where as another one it got stopped in between. Am expecting its because of too many async call

UPDATE
sample code

```
 @Async
        public void download(){
    //download file from server
    }
    public void callDownload(){
    for( int i =0; i <100000; i++)
      download();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depend on how the async call is implemented.  You need to give a concrete example.  How are you making the calls, the technology used to implement the call, the caller and the callee, etc, etc.  (But Thread.sleep is probably not "fine".)

Comment: (Hint: Java doesn't have asynchronous methods.  Java method calls are inherently synchronous.)

Comment: @StephenC : Thanks for the quick reply. i have placed a sample code in the question

Comment: is that a spring annotation? try looking in the docs for spring if so.

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not sure if your edit accurately reflects what the OP had in mind: he didn't mention `Spring` **anywhere** and the only clue is an annotation in a code sample provided later, that may or may not be a Spring annotation (it's not like Spring has a trademark for it...)

Answer (score 2):

OK so what we are actually talking about is asynchronous calls implemented using the Spring `@async` mechanism.

According to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async:

> Simply put – annotating a method of a bean with `@Async` will make it execute *in a separate thread*; i.e. the caller will not wait for the completion of the called method.

and

> By default, Spring uses a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to actually run these methods asynchronously.

Looking at the [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) for `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, we see:

> TaskExecutor implementation that fires up a new Thread for each task, executing it asynchronously.
>
> Supports limiting concurrent threads through the "concurrencyLimit" bean property. By default, the number of concurrent threads is unlimited.
>
> NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads! Consider a thread-pooling TaskExecutor implementation instead, in particular for executing a large number of short-lived tasks.

So from this we can conclude that (unless you have done some extra tuning that you have not mentioned):

1. Each one of your asynchronous calls uses a separate thread.
2. There is no thread pooling to recycle threads.
3. The mechanism does not limit the number of threads created.

Creating a thread is expensive, and each thread consumes a significant amount of memory.  So I expect that what is happening is that you are overloading the JVM with an excessive number of threads, and it is grinding .. to .... a ........ halt.  (Either due to a GC death-spiral, virtual memory thrashing or maybe network congestion due to trying to do too many downloads at the same time.)

Basically, this naive approach won't scale.   A better idea would be to use an ExecutorService with a bounded thread pool, and submit the download requests as tasks.  The executor service will queue the tasks and submit them to its pool of worker threads.  You should tune the size of the thread pool so that it doesn't overwhelm your local memory / compute, your network connection ... and the remote servers that you are HAMMERING with parallel downloads.

It is also possible that the remote servers are throttling your downloads ... because your massively parallel downloads *look like* a DOS attack.

Answer (score 0):

There are two part with async calls. A client & a Server(may be).

1. Maximum number of async call(actually executing in parallel) will depend on thread resource you have on your client machine). You can invoke the method as many time you want but the actual execution will be scheduled by progamming language call stack or Operating system of that machine. So, the answer is - It depends on the type of resource you have.
2. It will also depend on what type of call you are making - Is it a server / network call? Are you making a request to database, queue etc. These systems may have their own limit for number of request they can process in parallel and make rest of the call blocking. It depends.

So, from language perspective you are free to make any number of calls until you hit hardware limit.

It is always good to reasonably limit your async parallel call based on how many threads/processor available.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** this post answers the OP which was "Maximum number of async call at a time using java" (nothing related to Spring) before it was edited by 3rd party.

**Original answer follows:**
Answering the part *"the best way to restrict"* is using a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with just few threads: the fact that the method is asynchronous means that we do **not** need a separate thread for each outstanding call. (In fact, in case of async calls, setting a thread pool size to anything bigger than the number of available CPU cores will most probably slightly decrease performance because of unnecessary context switching).

First, an async API must be able to accept a callback someway to handle the results. Usually, a given method either accepts a callback parameter or returns a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). Assuming the first option, `download` method should have a signature similar to this:

```java
public void download(Consumer<String> resultHandler);
```

So now we can limit the number of concurrent calls like this:

```java
final var CONCURRENT_CALL_LIMIT = 20;
final var TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_CALLS = 100000;

final var concurrentCallLimiter = new Semaphore(CONCURRENT_CALL_LIMIT);
final var concurrentCallLimiterExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        2, 2, 0l, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<>());

for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_CALLS; i++) {
    concurrentCallLimiterExecutor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            concurrentCallLimiter.acquire();
            download((result) -> {
                concurrentCallLimiter.release();
                System.out.println(result); // or do whatever else with the result
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    });
}
```

The 2 threads of `concurrentCallLimiterExecutor` acquire `concurrentCallLimiter` semaphore permit and then call the async `download`. When the semaphore gives out all of its 20 permits, subsequent `download` calls will be enqueued in executor's queue. Once some download finishes, it releases semaphore permit, allowing the next download from the queue to start.

Remember to call `concurrentCallLimiterExecutor.shutdown()` at app shutdown ;-)