# How execute a thread before another?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a small question for you.

I have two threads:

- `HelloThread` - This prints "hello" five times.
- `GoodbyeThread` - This prints "Goodbye" five times.

I would like the `HelloThread` run first and after it's done the `GoodbyeThread` run.
I have already solve this problem with semaphore (but semaphore doesn't really true java way, it's more C way).

### `HelloThread.java`

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package modifiedthreadhellogoodbye;

    import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    class HelloThread implements Runnable {

        private final Object lock;
        //private final Semaphore lock;

        public HelloThread(Semaphore lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        public HelloThread(Object lock) {
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int pause;
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Hello!");
                    pause = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
                    try {
                        sleep(pause);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(HelloThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
                lock.notifyAll();
                System.out.println("Outsite hello");
            }
                //lock.release();

        }
    }
```

### `GoodbyeThread.java`

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package modifiedthreadhellogoodbye;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class GoodbyeThread implements Runnable {

    int pause;
    //private final Semaphore lock;
    private final Object lock;

    public GoodbyeThread(Semaphore lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public GoodbyeThread(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Inside the synchronized");
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GoodbyeThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //lock.acquire();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                pause = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
                try {
                    sleep(pause);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(GoodbyeThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my class who run thread :

```
public class ModifiedThreadObject {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    //private final Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(0);

    public ModifiedThreadObject() {
        HelloThread hello = new HelloThread(lock);
        GoodbyeThread goodbye = new GoodbyeThread(lock);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(hello);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(goodbye);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

The main idea is `GoodbyeThread` should `wait()` for the signal from `HelloThread`.
If `GoodbyeThread` is run first, it's work perfectly, but `HelloThread` runs first I have the following output:

```
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Outsite hello
Inside the synchronized
```

`HelloThread` sends a `notifyAll()`, but nobody is waiting so the "signal" is lost ...

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Why is Semaphore not "the right way" if it works for you?

Comment: This is just an academic example. I don't remember where but I have read java don't follow the mutex / semaphore pattern because it's too much complicated

Comment: "It's too complicated"? According to who, and in what aspect? Why would the class be available if you weren't supposed to use it?

Comment: Another option by the way is to use an observer pattern, where the goodbye thread listens for a trigger to start, which is fired by the hello thread when it's finished.

Comment: I have not think about observer pattern, it could be good solution too. 
I have read the good way for synchronize the thread in java is follow the notify / wait pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, I'd question the use of separate threads at all here. If you want one thing to happen after another, just use a single thread.

However, it's easy to wait until one thread has finished - just use `join`:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(hello);
Thread t2 = new Thread(goodbye);
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
```

That way you don't need any synchronization within the "hello" or "goodbye" code.

If you want anything more complicated, I'd recommend looking in the `java.util.concurrent` package. While you *can* use `wait()` and `notify()`, it's generally a better idea to use higher-level constructs. For example, for a producer/consumer scenario, you may well want to use [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) rather than implement it all yourself.

Comment: Beaten to it by seconds. + 1

Comment: Hello, I understand another method exist, but this is just an academic example for understand the thread synchronizing.

Comment: @Nymeria: Well if you want a solution that works for a different situation, you should show that different situation. It's very hard to produce a solution to requirements we don't actually know about.

Comment: I'm looking for synchronizing thread properly in java. I'm new in java and I wondering what is a good way for executing a thread before another (like producer / consumer problem)

Comment: @Nymeria: If you want to do *everything for a whole thread's operation* before starting the other one, then you use `Thread.join`. That's not even slightly like the producer/consumer pattern, however, where they're interleaved. There are plenty of articles around producer/consumer patterns in Java.

Comment: BlockingQueue sound very interesting ! Thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can achive that with help of [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), simple example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... s){

        final CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 5;
                while((i--)>0)
                    System.out.println("hello");
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        });


        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    cdl.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("goodbye");
            }
        });

        t2.start();
        t1.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's a good solution, CountDownLatch is a kind of semaphore ?

Comment: You can read comparison of them [CountDownLatch vs. Semaphore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184147/countdownlatch-vs-semaphore).

Comment: A lot of ways to synchronize threads, you need to choose one according to situation .

Comment: Ah okay, I have understand, CountDownLatch is more like pthread_barrier in C. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

While John Skeet provided the correct way to do this type of thing, it may also be useful to understand exactly what the program flow error is as well.

In `GoodbyeThread`:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    System.out.println("Inside the synchronized");
    try {
        lock.wait();
    }
```

So, after aquiring the lock, you insist on waiting on it? The problem with this is that `HelloThread` has already terminated by the time `GoodbyeThread` aquires it; when `HelloThread` calls `notifyAll`, that does nothing because nobody is waiting on the lock yet.

---

Another issue is the use of `Semaphore`. As written, your classes do not make use of any feature of `Semaphore`, and in fact, will cast it to an `Object` if given one anyway. You should erase all mention of `Semaphore` from your code, as it is unnecessary and potentially confusing.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I'm looking for a solution to waiting "properly" in GoodBye thread.

Many solution was given (observator pattern, countDownLatch)