# Why does Java have both CountDownLatch and CyclicBarrier?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading multi threading and came across these to multithreading concepts, I read the difference and when we should be using these, but I am not able to understand why Java has two classes which do same work?

`CyclicBarrier` can do everything that `CountDownLatch` does, then why is`CountDownLatch` in the Java standard library?

Comment: Sometimes classes may overlap in functionality. That doesn't mean that all classes that could be potentially replaced by another class are unnecessary.

Comment: That is the question, what is the different functionality here that could get overridden? I need to know in this particular case. But wherever I read I get only one answer that one is reusable and other is not and that is the only diffrence. I would prefer to use reusable all the time, even though I am not reusing currently, Then why java has two classes? Question is still unanswered   -- Thank for reply man

Comment: Why would you use the reusable `CyclicBarrier` in a situation where you need to have single time functionality? That could result in a bug!

Comment: Why and what type of bug will I get?

Comment: The kind of bug that you get from not using the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 7):

A short, not overly detailed answer... And first a link to their respective javadocs:

- [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html);
- [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

tl;dr: the main difference is that unlike a `CyclicBarrier`, once a `CountDownLatch` is done and over with, it cannot be reused. The javadoc mentions it explicitly:

> This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.

And indeed, we find that a `CyclicBarrier` has a method called `.reset()`, which does what it means. Not only that, but [there is a version of the constructor of a `CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#CyclicBarrier-int-java.lang.Runnable-) which associated a `Runnable` to be run each time the barrier is "tripped" (that is what the javadoc says; don't ask me).

So, those are indeed different, for the simple fact that one is reusable (`CyclicBarrier`) while the other is not (`CountDownLatch`).

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear before, let me rephrase it. I have gone through many posts explaining deffrence between these two.  My question is, we can do everything using CyclicBarrier that CountDownLatch does, with no extra overhead, then why does java provides these two separate classes?

Comment: You didn't read my answer properly. Again: you cannot reuse a `CountDownLatch`; you can reuse a `CyclicBarrier`. No, one is not a replacement for the other.

Comment: I know that CountDownLatch is not reusaable where as CyclicBarrier is, no doubt about this, its clear. Let me put it this way, why shuld I use CountDownLatch when I can use CyclicBarrier? do I get any performance or any other type of benifite if I use it? I can use CyclicBarrier even though i dont want to reuse it, right? If so then why does java provides two different classes, which can be achieved by one class?

Comment: Well, why would you use a reusable barrier when you need a one shot barrier only? And yes, very probably, the implementation of a `CountDownLatch` is optimized for that one shot scenario. Now, as I said, the answer I gave is not very detailed so you might want to _fully read_ the javadoc of each as to why you would want to use one over the other.

Answer (score 6):

> CyclicBarrier can do everything that CountDownLatch does, then why
>   isCountDownLatch in the Java standard library?

Not really.

The biggest difference between the two is not that one is reusable and the other is not. The difference is when state is changed. For latch - when *someone* (that's the key!) calls *countDown()* method, while for Barrier - when a *thread* (that's the key) reaches *await()* method.

So basically, we have different units of measurement here - one operates in terms of number of calls to *countDown()* while the other with number of waiting *threads*

Consider 2 examples:

```
// thread 1
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  latch.countDown() //perfectly fine
}

//thread 2
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  barrier.await() //oops 
}
```

Considering that effectively both are counters for different things their features somehow intersect.

Comment: This perfectly answers the question. The accepted one did not point out the core different between the two.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about a common question. Sometimes indeed some classes provided by JDK are functionally overlapping.

Another example is `CountDownLatch` and `Semaphore`. Basically you can replace one with another without much difference in functionality. This post: [CountDownLatch vs. Semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184147/countdownlatch-vs-semaphore) may help in your confusion.

I think you can choose one which can make your code easier to understand.  In your case, if you use a `CyclicBarrier` it will never reset itself, so you would better use `CountDownLatch` which makes the code easier to understand.

Take the constructor of `Semaphore` for example: JDK provides two constructors

```
1     public Semaphore(int permits) {
2         sync = new NonfairSync(permits);
3     }
```

and

```
1     public Semaphore(int permits, boolean fair) {
2         sync = fair ? new FairSync(permits) : new NonfairSync(permits);
3     }
```

we can use `Semaphore(3,false)` to replace `Semaphore(3)` without any difference, both of them are constructing a Non-fair version semaphore. But why does JDK still provide two versions of constructors? Because choosing the right one from them can make the code easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 cents:

The `CountDownLatch` allows thread A to wait for thread B, but not requiring thread B to wait for thread A. This can be used on scenario when one thread is required to work uninterruptedly, while the other must synchronize on some points on that thread.

On the other hand `CyclicBarrier` requires the 2 threads to synchronize on each other, which is the core different between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the standard differences, the reason for having both is that they offer different functionalities and not really completely overlap. For example-

1. CyclicBarrier allows you to supply a Runnable that is executed everytime the barrier point is met, this can be used to update some common state, this can't be done by CountDownLatch.
2. In CyclicBarrier, if one thread encounters exception, all threads exit with an exception, this can't be done in CountDownLatch.

So, it really depends on your usecase which one to use.