# What's the point of CountDownLatch in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore, countdownlatch

`CountDownLatch` in java is a high-level synchronization utility which is used to prevent a particular thread to start processing until all threads are ready.

But, `Semaphore` can totally do the same thing. So, **what's the merit of `CountDownLatch`?**

One more question: If `CountDownLatch` do have some merits, **Why It was designed to used only once?** I think it's easy to add a set method to reset the count.

Comment: Even I though to mark this question as duplicate but due to second query, I did not do it >  Why It was designed to used only once? I think it's easy to add a set method to reset the count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantically, they're different; and that matters, because it makes your code easier to read. When I see a Semaphore, I immediately start thinking "a limited amount of a shared resource." When I see a CountDownLatch, I immediately start thinking "a bunch of threads waiting for the 'go!' signal." If you give me the former in code that actually needs the latter, it's confusing.

In this sense, a Semaphore being used as a CountDownLatch is a bit like a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence); while technically correct, it leads people astray and confuses them.

In terms of more pragmatic uses, a CountDownLatch is just simpler if that's all you need. Simpler is better!

As for reusing a CountDownLatch, that would complicate its usage. For instance, let's say you're trying to queue up threads A, B, and C for some work. You have them await on the latch, and then you release it. Then you reset it, presumably to queue up threads D, E and F for some other work. But what happens if (due to a race condition), thread B hasn't actually been released from the first latch yet? What if it hadn't even gotten to the `await()` call yet? Do you close the gate on it, and tell it to wait with D, E and F for the second opening? That might even cause a deadlock, if the second opening depends on work that B is supposed to be doing!

I had the same questions you did about resetting when I first read about CountDownLatch. But in practice, I've rarely even wanted to reset one; each unit of "wait then go" (A-B-C, then D-E-F) naturally lends itself to creating its own CountDownLatch to go along with it, and things stay nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks, and why It was designed to used only once?

Comment: @expoter Because there are other classes that allow reuse. Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html): *This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).*

Answer (score 5):

A **Semaphore** with n blocks *when* 0 is reached.

A **CountDownLatch** of n blocks *till* 0 is reached. Then all continue at approximately the same time.

> So a semaphore is like a gate keeper at the disco, and a count down latch like a start shot at game courses.

Comment: @expoter If you create a `Semaphore` with N *permits*, you can [`acquire()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire--) N times, and call number N+1 to `acquire()` will block, i.e. it will only block *when* the permit count reaches zero. --- If you create a `CountDownLatch` with a count of N, any call to [`await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await--) will block *until* the count reaches zero, i.e. N calls to `countDown()`. --- Totally different functionality.

Comment: +1 (and I agree with @Andreas), but as a small note: `semaphore.acquire(0)` will still block until there are at least 0 permits, and a semaphore is allowed to have a negative number of permits, so it's actually fairly easy to use a Semaphore as basically a "CountUpLatch" (counting from -numberOfCounts to 0).

Comment: @Andreas indeed; is my formulation too unclear? Or are you reformulating a bit more clear and in technical detail?

Comment: @JoopEggen OP had commented that he didn't understand, so I clarified. That comment is now gone.

Comment: @yshavit a Semaphore is indeed a kind of anti-matter CountDownLatch, unfortunately not only a negative number of permits must be possible, but acquire would need to increase, or release would need to block. But it is good to have a view for such concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you create the Semaphore with -3 permits (which you can do), then any number of calls to acquire(0) will block until you call release() 3 times.

Comment: So every thread (that has to start simultaneously) calls release + acquire? Sorry @yshavit, I am now deeply involved in another DB related issue, so you may be entirely right. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Just a very simple substitution: countDown() turns into release(), and await() turns into acquire(0). So simple a regex could do it. :)

Comment: @yshavit aha, okay.

Answer (score 2):

> Semaphore can totally do the same thing. So, what's the point of CountDownLatch?

`Semaphore` maintains a set of permits. Each `acquire()` blocks if necessary until a permit is available, and then takes it. Each `release()` adds a permit, potentially releasing a blocking acquirer.

However, no actual permit objects are used; *the Semaphore just keeps a count of the number available and acts accordingly*.

***`Semaphore` is blocking the entry to enter critical section and `CountDownLatch` is blocking the execution of main thread unless other threads complete their tasks***.

Have a look at this SE question for more details:

[CountDownLatch vs. Semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184147/countdownlatch-vs-semaphore)

> If CountDownLatch do have some points, Why It was designed to used only once?

If you want to use it repeatedly, use [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called cyclic because it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

Javadocs of CountDownLatch quote that :

A CountDownLatch is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. *If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.*