# Wait for a thread to successfully start

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm wondering how to log information when a server has successfully started. I cannot do this as simple as that:

```
createServer().start(Exit.NEVER);
System.out.println("Server is running...");
```

because the instruction `createServer().start(Exit.NEVER)` doesn't return back. This is a call to external library that uses a method with a loop similar to `while(true)`.
I cannot also run the server in a new thread and then log information about successful start because the server may throw exception and hence there was a failure.

```
public void start () {
        new Thread("Server") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createServer().start(Exit.NEVER);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }
        }.start();

        System.out.println("Server is running...");
}
```

Last solution I can think of is to wait a couple of second after `createServer().start(Exit.NEVER)` and then log the successful start as there was no exception thrown. This is not a perfect solution as we can wait for example 5 seconds and the log the successful start but one second later the server may throw exception.

How do I then can tell whether the server has started successfully and hence log this information?

**EDIT**

The server I'm using is `Takes` https://github.com/yegor256/takes.

Comment: You could use a Countdown latch to signal when the server is up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184147/countdownlatch-vs-semaphore

Comment: if your server does not have a return value for the start (or a kind of busy inditor for the starting process)  - does it have a method you can call to check, whether it is operational?

Comment: What is this "server?" What does it do inside that `start(...)` call? Is there no way that you can pre-load an "event" or a "request" that will cause it to call back to your own code from inside the `start(...)` method?

Comment: @Slimu I read about that COurtnDownLatch, but I don;t know how to implement this in my screnario.

Comment: Would another way looking at it help? The Server class cannot be determined when to start(most probably can't be modified), the alternative way is to create a countdown loop to check an API if it's started, an endpoint like /ping. So the (loop+100)ping(endloop) will run if it's over timeout and exit, else wait till it gets a response to 1 of ping/.

Comment: Looks like some kind of a web server. Couldn't you have another thread in your program wait a few seconds for the server to start up, and then send it a HEAD request? If anything comes back, then the server probably is up.

Comment: P.S., I don't understand why you think you can't run the server in a new thread. You expressed concern that "the server may throw exception..." OK. So, why not catch the exception and log it? (Your example shows catching the exception and re-throwing it, but throwing from a thread's `run()` method isn't especially useful.) Anyway, I don't know what you'd do after logging the exception. That would be up to you to decide.